# Sublime Text 2 : Having trouble making an OpenGL sublime-build

Tags: c, opengl, sublimetext2, sublime-build

Just trying to set up a sublime-build for my OpenGL coding on Windows 8.1.

This is what I have:

```
{
"cmd": [ "gcc -o \"$file\" \"$file_base_name\" -lGLU -lGL -lglut && ./\"$file_base_name\""],
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
"selector": ["source.c"],
"shell": true  
}
```

The error that I'm getting is `gcc: error: "tute2": Invalid argument` when trying to compile tute2.c.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace

```
"cmd": [ "gcc -o \"$file\" \"$file_base_name\" -lGLU -lGL -lglut && ./\"$file_base_name\""],
```

with

```
"cmd": [ "gcc -o $file_base_name $file -lGLU -lGL -lglut && ./$file_base_name"],
```

and try again.

Comment: I get the error:
`gcc: error: "G:\Uni\test\tute2.c": Invalid argument`

Comment: @An0nx It looks like `"` also become part of the argument, try to remove them, as I did in the updated answer.

Comment: Seems to have fixed that problem, now I'm getting

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGLU
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lGL
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I'm not exactly sure what it's asking because it refers to multiple different folders there.

Comment: @An0nx You need to add arguments like `-L/path/to/libGLU` and so on to `gcc`.

Comment: how exactly is that done? something like this? `"cmd": [ "gcc -o $file_base_name $file -L/C:/MinGW/lib/glut32.lib -lGLU -lGL -lglut -lglut32win && ./$file_base_name"],`

Comment: @An0nx If all those libraries are under the same directory `C:/MinGW/lib/`, then that option should be `-LC:/MinGW/lib/`. Otherwise you need to add those directories one by one.

Comment: Is it looking for `glut32.lib` because that is in my `C:/MinGW/lib/` folder and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @An0nx I am not sure, on Linux with `-lGLU` `ld` will look for `libGLU.so`, others are similar. If your system has those files, you should give them a try.